# Markdown looks different when viewing edit history or suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering

I just reviewed [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27131612), and the "rendered output" tab doesn't look the same as the answer when rendering the same markdown.

Here's the markdown being rendered:

```
##Model##
    Business Data + Business Logic + Business Rules

##View##
    Application UI

##ViewModel
    Wrapper Over Model which is ealily readable/bindable by View
    using minimum Effort/Code.

 1) **`IDataErrorInfo`** - Should go into `ViewModel`  
 2) **`INotifyPropertyChanged`** - Should go into `ViewModel`, and `Model` (if needed, not recommended for Model)  
 3) **`Public Properties`**- Yes of course a `Model` should have them.
```

This is how it looks on the suggested edits review page:

[image: The suggested edits page for the answer]

And this is the actual answer:

[image: The actual answer]

This can also be seen on the answer's [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4453396/revisions).

Comment: Probably related to last paragraph of *"What you can expect"* in the [commonmark change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark). As far as I understand it, this is not a bug, is to be expected, and it affects certain posts following the change that have not yet been edited since

Comment: I call "too much formatting" on that post. Why is "Business Data + Business Logic + Business Rules" formatted as code or, really, anything besides `IDataErrorInfo` & `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Dunno, I fixed the formatting that was _already_ in place but took no creative steps towards improving it. I was tempted to remove the code formatting, but with it the text at least looked like it applied to the headings, without it... Eh.... The list looks very out of place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer was written in 2010 when we didn't use CommonMark yet. During CommonMark migration, most posts were migrated to the new markdown flavor, but this was done only for the most common scenarios. Everything else should be edited manually. The same has happened to [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024638/1839439). It looked OK before migration, but after the migration, formatting was broken. I had to adjust it manually.

In this case, the suggested edit didn't fix the markdown formatting. Such an edit should be rejected or improved. When suggesting edits you should fix all problems you can see and the broken formatting should be one of them.

If you need to fix this problem in the future just change

```
##Model##
```

to

```
## Model
```

Comment: Or to `## Model ##` likewise if you fancy the symmetrical formatting.